# How to get the second last argument from shell script?

Tags: bash, unix, arguments, sh

I want to get the second last item given to a shell program. Currently I do it like this:

```
file1_tmp="${@: -2}"
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=" "
count=0
for value in $file1; do
  if [[ count -e 0 ]]; then
    file1=$value
  fi
    count=1
done
oldIFS=$IFS
```

I'm sure that there is a much easier way to do this. So how can I get the second last argument from a shell script input in as few lines as possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
set -- "first argument" "second argument" \
       "third argument" "fourth argument" \
       "fifth argument"
second_to_last="${@:(-2):1}"
echo "$second_to_last"
```

Note the quoting, which ensures that arguments with whitespace stick together -- which your original solution doesn't do.

Comment: The differences between `$@` and `$*` don't matter when you're only retrieving one item, because they control how subsequent items are joined together (or, as the case may be, not). I still recommend `$@` as more clear to a reader that the desired output is an individual element with no joining operations taking place. Or did you have a more specific question?

Comment: ...as for `(-2)` vs a space before the `-`, the point is just to be unambiguous to the parser that we *don't* want `:-` to be parsed as a single token. Either approach accomplishes it.

Comment: I found (-2) this confusing as it is also used for arrays and sub shell. I guess that is not how it is used here.

Comment: Determining array indices is an operation with a mathematical result, so bash's parser operates in an arithmetic context (the same kind of context that `$(( ))` creates); so parens have the same meaning they have in any other mathematical operation, as grouping / precedence / order-of-operations with no implied subshell.

Answer (score 6):

In bash/ksh/zsh you can simply `${@: -2:1}`

```
$ set a b c d 
$ echo ${@: -1:1}
c
```

In POSIX sh you can use `eval`:

```
$ set a b c d 
$ echo $(eval "echo \$$(($#-2))")
c
```

Comment: The quoting in this answer is correct for zsh, but incorrect in any POSIX-compliant shell (such as bash or ksh).

Comment: This can be done in Bourne without eval -- for instance, by shifting args inside a function: `penultimate() { while [ "$#" -gt 2 ]; do shift; done; printf '%s\n' "$1"; }; penultimate "$@"`

Comment: (This is where I kick my former self for being sloppy about naming -- that's not valid [1970s] Bourne, which doesn't support `$(( ))`; rather, it's valid [1990s] POSIX sh).

Comment: When I run your first snippet, `$ echo ${@: -1:1}` prints `d`. Don't you mean `$ echo ${@: -2:1}` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
n=$(($#-1))
second_to_last=${!n}
echo "$second_to_last"
```

Answer (score 5):

There are some options for all bash versions:

```
$ set -- aa bb cc dd ee ff
$ echo "${@: -2:1}   ${@:(-2):1}   ${@:(~1):1}   ${@:~1:1}   ${@:$#-1:1}"
ee   ee   ee   ee   ee
```

The (`~`) is the bitwise negation operator (search in the ARITHMETIC EVALUATION section).
It means *flip all bits*.

The selection even could be done with (integer) variables:

```
$ a=1  ; b=-a; echo "${@:b-1:1}   ${@:(b-1):1}   ${@:(~a):1}   ${@:~a:1}   ${@:$#-a:1}"
ee   ee   ee   ee   ee

$ a=2  ; b=-a; echo "${@:b-1:1}   ${@:(b-1):1}   ${@:(~a):1}   ${@:~a:1}   ${@:$#-a:1}"
dd   dd   dd   dd   dd
```

For really old shells, you must use eval:

```
eval "printf \"%s\n\" \"\$$(($#-1))\""
```